# How to get the USB VID, PID and serial number of a device in Ubuntu using C++ from /dev/xxx path

Tags: c++, ubuntu

When USB cameras are plugged into Linux a device appears in the /dev folder.  For example, the first camera will appear as video0.  In the system we’re building, with multiple cameras, we get video0, video1 and video2.

My requirement is to to programmatically read a USB camera’s VendorID (VID), ProductID (PID) and serial number using C++.

Currently, we use UDEV rules to map a specific device to something like /dev/camera_one; but we'd like to programmatically read the serial number and check that the device has not been changed.

We can enumerate all USB devices using the libudev, so we know we can get the information from libudev ( https://github.com/gavv/snippets/blob/master/udev/udev_monitor_usb.c )

But how can we use libudev to extract the required VID, PID and serial number given the /dev/videoN path.

Comment: Doesn't `udev_device_new_from_syspath` do what you need?

Comment: @Ulrich -  udev_device_new_from_syspath() doesn't work for the /dev/<device> style path. It only works for paths starting with /sys from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet the does exactly what is being asked:

```
void ReadUsbIdentifiers(std::string dev_path){
    auto udev = udev_new();
    if (!udev) { return; }

    struct stat statbuf;
    if (stat(dev_path.c_str(), &statbuf) < 0) { return; }
    auto type =  S_ISBLK(statbuf.st_mode) ? 'b' : S_ISCHR(statbuf.st_mode) ? 'c' : 0;

    auto opened_dev = udev_device_new_from_devnum(udev, type, statbuf.st_rdev);
    auto dev = opened_dev;

    while (dev != nullptr)
    {
        auto serial = udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, "serial");
        if (nullptr == serial)
        {
            dev = udev_device_get_parent(dev);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "VID: " <<  udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, "idVendor") << std::endl;
            std::cout << "PID: " <<  udev_device_get_sysattr_value(dev, "idProduct") << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Serial Number: " <<  serial << std::endl;
        }
    }
    if (opened_dev) { udev_device_unref(opened_dev); }
    udev_unref(udev);
}
```

There are two significant aspects to the code.

Firstly, you use the linux function stat() to get the /dev file’s status, and this status contains the st_rdev which is the device_ID.  This can then be used in the UDEV function udev_device_new_from_devnum().

Secondly, the device returned by udev_device_new_from_devnum() is a ‘child’ of the physical USB device, and it does not itself know the serial number, vendor Id or product Id.  Instead you need to get this information from the parent of the device, or the parent’s parent.

Comment: That code doesn't work because serial can be shared by many devices, but different inputs